# Are the posteriors "different"? How does one discuss the result?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, proportion, posterior, ecology

First, I realize this may be a basic question.  However, when I search the web for references on this issue, I run into the problem of wondering if the description I'm reading is applicable to the example I have in mind.  So while I have an idea of what the answers to the questions below may be, I am not yet very confident in my Bayesian thinking.  Any guidance would be appreciated.  Thank you.

An analysis is carried out in a Bayesian framework and yields a posterior distribution of a parameter bounded between 0 and 1.  This parameter is estimated for 1 species at two points in time (two years), but under 2 very different conditions.  The two years are analyzed separately.  In one year the average of the posterior of the parameter might be around 30%, and in the other around 45%.

My initial reaction is to carry out a hypothesis test, and to ask, "are these two estimates "significantly" different?"  Given the Bayesian nature of the analysis, is it meaningful to ask this question? Is it reasonable to expect a "yes or no" answer, similar to what would be expected in a frequentist setting?

Say that the question is meaningful.  How does one go about finding an answer?  If I compare the 95% credible intervals, and find out that the CI's of the parameter from the two years overlap, does that mean that there is no difference?

A similar approach would be to introduce a new variable in the model, call it YR, and allow YR to reflect the affect of the 2nd year on the estimate of the original parameter.  I could look at the estimate of YR, and ask if its 95% credible interval includes 0 or not.

The parameter estimates are fairly uncertain --- if a posterior has a distribution with a mean of 30%, its  1st and 3rd quartiles could range between 20% and 40% (and the 45% year would be between 35% and 55%). Say that the parameter estimates have 95% CI's that overlap, or that YR is estimated as 15%, but its CI includes 0.  Does this mean that the analysis is suggesting that the two years are "not different", or does one simply state that the years were 15% different, ± some uncertainty?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most appropriate summary for this application is just to simply state that the years were 15% different, ± some uncertainty. Here's why: first, the concept of statistical significance *per se* doesn't fit naturally into the Bayesian framework; second, in this application it's not really plausible that the parameter takes the exact same value in the two data sets, so you might as well just estimate the difference directly.

The interpretation of the fact that 0 is within the error bars is this: the data do not strongly indicate the sign of the difference. That's the Bayesian equivalent of "lack of statistical significance". But even if the result is not significant in this sense, you may (or may not) be able to make a scientifically interesting claim about the magnitude of the difference.

Comment: Excellent, I think I get it. My strategy for this type of thing is to be transparent about uncertainty, but to not be afraid to say something like, "the estimate was higher in the second year than the first"  I avoid the use of the word "significant". If you have any hand references, I'd be glad if you could share them.  Thanks!

Comment: @rbatt, I don't have any references to hand that are directly on point; my thinking here basically echoes that of [Andrew Gelman](http://andrewgelman.com/2004/12/29/type_1_type_2_t/), author of [Bayesian Data Analysis](http://www.amazon.com/Bayesian-Analysis-Edition-Chapman-Statistical/dp/1439840954/) (3rd edition soon to be released).